# Why RouterModule uses forRoot() AND forChild()?

Tags: angular

Why Angular RouterModule uses forRoot() and forChild()?

I already read the article about forRoot pattern and how to defend provider singleton from multiple import (https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#the-forroot-pattern) and I know why Routermodule uses forRoot().

But My question is, Why it uses both `[ RouterModule.forRoot() <=> RouterModule.forChild() ]` ? Is it not ok just using `[ RouterModule.forRoot() <=> RouterModule ]`?

Why angular developers forced users to write a few more alphabets for `FORCHILD()` ? Just for explicitness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TR; DL: I misunderstood `RouterModule`. `forChild()` provides `services` that should not be provided by `forRoot()`. So `forChild()` can't be replaced by `RouterModule`.

## Misunderstanding

After I read the source code of `RouterModule`, I realized that I had misunderstood.

What I thought:

`RouterModule` has only `declarations`(`components`, `directives`, `pipes`) and all `services` are provided from `forRoot()`. Then `forChild()` will be perfect subset of `forRoot()`.

As a diagram:

[image]

So I was been wondering if only `forRoot` provides `services` and neither `forChild()` and `RouterModule` does not, then what's the difference between `forChild()` and `RouterModule`.

But I was wrong.

## Correction

Unlike what I thought, `forChild()` was also providing `services` which should not be provided by `forRoot()`. One of the `services` provided by `forChild()` is user-defined routes, which should obviously have each instances.

And the correct diagarm looks like this:

[image]

I misunderstood because I've never seen `services` that should be provided multiple time, which its singleton could be destroyed.

## Conclusion

There is a reason why `forChild()` is made separately.. `forChild()` is not a subset of `forRoot()`, and is clearly different with `RouterModule` itself.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between forRoot() and forChild() :

- forRoot() includes router services itself
- forChild() doesn't include router services itself

So It's recommanded to use forRoot() in your 'root' module.

forChild() is used in your other module to optimize performance and don't reload router services for nothing.

https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule#forChild

Comment: I understand, but is it just enough to make RouterModule.forChild() as RouterModule? So we can use RouterModule vs RouterModule.forRoot(), not RouterModule.forChild() vs RouterModule.forRoot()

Answer (score 0):

RouterModule defines Providers and Declarations.

> If a module defines both providers and declarations (components, directives, pipes), then loading the module in multiple feature modules would duplicate the registration of the service. This could result in multiple service instances and the service would no longer behave as a singleton.

Source: https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

forRoot and forChild tells the module which parts to import, so you don't get multiple instances of services. Without a central service (a singleton), you'd get all kind of unexpected behaviour when accessing the service.

forChild prevents the import of the service, which otherwise would break the singleton.